# SQL - Referential integrity

Tags: sqlite, referential-integrity

seems like my problem pretty much describes GC (Garbage Collector) but I don't want to make a procedure to run every X time. so this is my question:
I have three tables or more, refer to those as A,B,C.
C holds some columns and A & B refer to those columns.
A & B data can be deleted -> and here comes my question: 
I'd like the referential to go as when there are no valid references to C, the referenced row will get deleted, since it's not in use.
I thought of adding an auto_increment to C, and make A & B refer to the index, and just keep multiple of the same data, and just delete the attached. This hardly seems like the most reasonable solution.
If anyone could point some light on my problem, that would be great. 
Thank you.

**EDIT:** I'm using SQLite.

Comment: You are looking for cascading delete, maybe triggers. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: cascading delete will delete the reference on the first delete no? Since I want to have multiple references to the same row, I don't want it to be deleted on the first delete.

Comment: Also making sure I stated correctly. I want to make my logic as when I delete the reference, the actual referenced row will be deleted, this is the opposite of cascade as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement it using a reference counter:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_in_b AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE A SET refcounter = refcounter + 1 WHERE id = new.foreignkey;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER remove_from_b AFTER DELETE ON B
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE A SET refcounter = refcounter - 1 WHERE id = old.foreignkey;
  DELETE FROM A WHERE id = old.foreignkey AND refcounter = 0;
END;
```

Comment: interesting, this seems like what I wanted. but is it possible to have the same Trigger for multiple tables? I need those triggers to be on two tables (A&B when C is the referenced)

Comment: Yes, that is indeed possible.

Comment: I need to make four triggers with the same code? or can I apply same trigger to multiple tables?

Comment: Of course, a trigger only works on exactly ONE table, so you will need to define multiple triggers.